# взаимодействие классов

Tags: java, android, классы

Есть класс в первой activity (SHAsalt) который солит и хешит пароль:

```
public class SHAsalt {

        public static void main2(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            String passwordToHash = "password";
            byte[] salt = getSalt();

            String securePassword = get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);
            System.out.println(securePassword);
        }

        private static String get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(String passwordToHash, byte[] salt)
        {
            String generatedPassword = null;
            try {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                md.update(salt);
                byte[] bytes = md.digest(passwordToHash.getBytes());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=0; i< bytes.length ;i++)
                {
                    sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
                }
                generatedPassword = sb.toString();
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return generatedPassword;
        }



        //Add salt
        private static byte[] getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
        {
            SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            sr.nextBytes(salt);
            return salt;
        }
    }
```

Пытаюсь вызывать метод в другом классе другой activity (login) для получения результата "securePassword":

```
        public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

public EditText login;
public EditText pass;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
private InputStream is;
Main url;
TextView textView3;
String random;
String random2;
PasswordGenerator simgen;
SHAsalt shasalt;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
       /*
        //Генерируем символы из класса PasswordGenerator
        new PasswordGenerator();
        //вызываем функцию генерирования (488 - 488) диапазон длинны пароля
        random = simgen.generate(488,488);
        //Выводим на экран
        textView3.setText("Random = "+random);
       */

        new SHAsalt();
        random2 = shasalt.main2();
        //Выводим на экран
        textView3.setText("Random = "+random2);

        }
```

Проблема: подчеркивает красным "()" в строке "random = shasolt.main2();" и подсвечивает

> main2 (string []) in SHAsalt cannot be applied to    ()

Как мне получить значение "securePassword" ?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том, что у вас метод `main2` ничего не возвращает, но вы при этом что то хотите присвоить в переменную `random`.

Вместо вызова метода `main2`, вызывете этот метод:

```
public static String getPassword(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte[] salt = getSalt();
    return get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(password, salt);
}
```

Comment: Та же история, только теперь пишет: "getPassword (string) in SHAsalt cannot be applied to ()"

Comment: Покажи код, как ты его вызываешь

Comment: `new SHAsalt();
random = shasalt.getPassword();
textView3.setText("Random = "+random);`

Comment: Я не знаю, может надо как-то использовать set и get ?

Comment: в сигнатуре метода getPassword определен параметр password. Это должна быть строка которую нужно передать в метод, соответственно компилятор ругается, что этой строки нет. нужно вызывать метод так String password=SHAsalt.getPassword("это мой пароль");

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но сейчас другая ошибка - "Unhandled exception: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmExeption" Я поправил вопрос, там я уточняю, что это также две разные activity. SHAsalt и Login.

Comment: Еще один факт. У меня есть похожая ситуация с другим классом, и все работает. Я так ее вызываю: new PasswordGenerator(); random2 = simgen.generate(**488**,**488**) (488 - это диапазон количества генерируемых символов, **generate** - это метод); textView3.setText("Random = "+random2);

Comment: @Lobs трудно что то сказать, нужен весь код.

Comment: Привел полный код 2х activity. Уже замучился экспериментировать с кодом. Если не делить на 2 activity, это не облегчит задачу? Я уже на все готов. Не хватает знаний у меня.

Comment: exception летит из метода getSalt? попробуй  создавать так securityRandom : SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom()

Comment: Мне кажется что все дело в аргументах. Потому что ошибка такая: `Error:(71, 28) Gradle: error: method main in class SHAsolt cannot be applied to given types;
required: String[]
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length` Если здесь: `random = shasolt.main` **(туточки)** `;` указать нужные....аргументы, то должно работать.

Comment: так и есть,   random2 = shasalt.main2(<сюда нужно передать массив или изменить метод main2 убрав из сигнатуры аргументы>);

Comment: Убирать аргументы уже пробовал - без толку. Остается узнать, как передать массив. Ты не в курсе?

Comment: @Lobs может не нужно пока программировать, а стоит книжки почитать?)

Comment: Так и сделал... пришлось кое-что переделать и таким образом обошел это "препятствие" ))

Answer (score 1):

У вас метод main2 принимает аргумент string[] , а вы в него ничего не передаете при вызове. Параметры которые принимает метод нигде не используются, поэтому можно сделать метод без параметров и всё. Сделайте так:

```
public static void main2() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String passwordToHash = "password";
        byte[] salt = getSalt();

        String securePassword = get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(passwordToHash, salt);
        System.out.println(securePassword);
    }
```

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка: "Unhandled exception: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmExeption".